# Created custom TextView doesn't applies layout params

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have a custom textView, which placed inside of LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        tools:text="Only on 22 of July, 2019"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And CustomTimerView with some logic

```
class CustomTimerView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attributeSet) {
    private var textView: TextView

    init {
        LinearLayout.inflate(context, R.layout.customTimer_layout, this)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.timerView)
    }

    fun setDates(ob: Promo) {
        val startDate = getStartDate(ob)
        val endDate = getEndDate(ob)

        if (startDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) != endDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            textView.text = getInDifferentMonths(context!!, ob)
        } else {
            if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                textView.text = getOnlyOneDay(context!!, ob)
            } else {
                textView.text = getInOneMonth(context!!, ob)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to remove LinearLayout, because it's useless. But when I go to only textView like

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/timerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        tools:text="Only on 22 of July, 2019"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

And code class like:

```
class CustomTimerView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : TextView(context, attributeSet) {

    init {
        TextView.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_timer_layout, null)
    }

    fun setDates(ob: Promo) {
        val startDate = getStartDate(ob)
        val endDate = getEndDate(ob)

        if (startDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) != endDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            this.text = getInDifferentMonths(context!!, ob)
        } else {
            if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                this.text = getOnlyOneDay(context!!, ob)
            } else {
                this.text = getInOneMonth(context!!, ob)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see a text, but it's looks like color and other params in TextView doesn't works. How to fix this?

Comment: If that layout is `custom_timer_layout`, it's completely pointless, and has no effect on your `CustomTimerView`. You would instead set the desired attributes on the `<com.example.app.CustomTimerView>` elements when used in your app's layouts.

Comment: Yep, but I have about 3 usage of this view in my project and put it in every view is not a perfect solution

Comment: Depending on the actual usage, you could create a separate layout that's just a `<com.example.app.CustomTimerView>` with the desired attribute settings, and `<include>` it where needed. Or, you could just set those attributes programmatically in `CustomTimerView` itself. Or, you could define a default style attribute and a default style for `CustomTimerView`, etc. In any case, that layout and the `inflate()` call you currently have there aren't doing anything.